# How to Create a string array by spliting a string?

Tags: c#

I am kinda stuck at the moment, i have a string of numbers which i dynamically get them from database, the range of numbers can be between 1 to 1 milion, something like this :

```
string str = "10000,68866225,77885525,3,787";
```

i need to create an array from it, i have tried this:

```
string[] strArr = { str.Replace(",", "").Split(',') };
```

but it doesnt work anyone has any solution i am all ours. Basically it needs to be like this:

```
string[] strArr = { "10000","68866225","77885525","3","787" };
```

Comment: `var strArr = "10000,68866225,77885525,3,787".Split(',');`

Comment: You are first removing the comma, and then trying to split on it?

Comment: This question shows no reseach effort of any kind, I would suggest studying about C# string manipulation at MSDN to get an idea about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attend:

```
string[] strArr = { str.Replace(",", "").Split(',') };
```

does not work because of two errors in the code:

1) You are removing all `,` before you are splitting at `,`:

```
str.Replace(",", "")
```

So basically you are trying to split this string: `"1000068866225778855253787"` at each `,`, which will result in an array containing only `"1000068866225778855253787"` because obviously there is no `,` to split on.

2) You are trying to assign an array to a string, because the `Split()` method already returns an array and you are trying to put this array into a field of `string[]` (because of the `{ }` around your assignment) and a field of `string[]` is of type string and not an array.

---

To get your expected output you have to do the `.Split(',')` on the original string, which includes all the `,` on which you are splitting. So just remove the `Replace()` call and you will get your desired output:

```
var str = "10000,68866225,77885525,3,787";
var strArr = str.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] strArr = str.Split(',');
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, i was wondering what if i had one number returning? something like this - string str = "1"; does it return an array as well?

Comment: @SmackDat yes, you will have an array with only one element which is `"1"`

Answer (score 0):

The split method already returns an array. Just take it out of the squiggly brackets.

```
string[] strArr = str.Split(',');
```

**Edit:** Sorry forgot to take out the .replace()

Answer (score 0):

The method `string.Split()` already returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] strArr =yourstring.Split(',');
```

This will  return an array with possible split counts , for example
"10000,68866225,77885525,3,787" will give array with the size of 4.